# Tag Wording - Legality

Tags: discussion, tags

Our FAQ states that:

"If a question requires a lawyer to answer it, we can't help. These situations are simply too specific and too complex to definitively answer on our site."

We also have tags such as United-states and United-kingdom.

The wording of the one for United -Kingdom is:

> Questions about the workplace that may specifically relate to cultures, customs **or laws** in the United Kingdom

The one for the United-states is nearly identical apart from the obvious difference between the named country.

So if Legal questions are off topic for this site then why do our tags say they are supposed to be used for questions about laws?

Was this an oversight or is it intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it was intentional at the time. Labor laws (and other relevant laws to the workplace) are different between the US and the UK (and between states in the US), so they need to be considered for questions specific to one place or the other. We don't (and can't) give legal advice, so a question about a law or laws is off-topic, but a question to which a law or laws may be relevant is ok, as long as it can be answered by (significantly) more than "There are laws about this, talk to a lawyer".

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1046/869) is a good example of that. There is an issue at hand that would be appropriate for legal action, but it can also be addressed in other ways. [Bethlakshmi's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1049/869) provides several potential solutions to the problem without the need for lawyers or legal expertise.

Comment: Thats a good example. I did try to tag you in chat where i raised a further issue, but it tagged the wrong one, if you wouldnt mind dropping in that would be fab. 

This answers the question though, i was a little confused at the difference but that tagged answer clears it up. Thanks